# Cross-reference to a Mediawiki-made website's URL partially not working

Tags: mediawiki

In words: I developed a website with Mediawiki 1.22.5 (PHP 5.3.3 (apache2handler), SQLite 3.6.20 with full-text search support) and now it's public through, say, www.myserver.com/~myname/mediawiki/index.php/website_name. The website has both a puclic and a private area (accessible with login).

Now, I register the website but under another domain, say, www.new_name.com, by making a cross-reference associated with the new domain. The problem is that, if I go on www.new_name.com I can surf on the public pages, but not all of them: for instance, when I click on the login button, as well as on the private pages, nothing happens, I just remain on the same page.

Any suggestion please?

P.S.: Sorry, if I do not provide other info, I'm not an expert in web development, but if you ask to provide more specific info I'll be glad to do it. Ciao.

Comment: Do your question is how to make the wiki accessible from both domains?

Comment: no, I wanted to make it accessible only from the domain I registered (www.new_name.com). I just solved the problem: from the domain registration's options, I have changed the IP address where the new domain has to point to, i.e., now it points to the IP of the server hosting the website. (When I did the registration, it maybe pointed to a wrong IP adress.) Thank you for your interest Nemo.

Comment: Great, please do post your solution as answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the domain registration's options, I have changed the IP address where the new domain has to point to, i.e., now it points to the IP of the server hosting the website. (When I did the registration, it maybe pointed to a wrong IP adress.)